# $B$ is Hermitian, $A$ is positive semidefinite $ \Rightarrow $ $tr(AB)$ is real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Let $A, B\in M_n$.

- $B$  is  Hermitian.
- $A$ is positive semidefinite.

why is $tr(AB)$ real?

*(We know $tr(AB) = tr(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive semi-definite, $A^{1/2}$ exists and is Hermitian too. Since $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$
$$
tr(AB)=tr(A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B)=tr(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})
$$
Since 
$$
(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^*=(A^{1/2})^*B^*(A^{1/2})^*=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}
$$ 
it is  Hermitian and thus all its eigenvalues are real. So $tr(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})$ is real.

Comment: I suppose this is a bit pedantic, but since $A$ is only positive *semi*-definite, $\sqrt{A}$ is not necessarily invertible, and so you should use the cyclic invariance property of trace when deriving $\text{tr}(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})$.